# Create a gif by appending previous frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, gif

I have been able to create a gif but it is made up of individual "frames". How can I retain the last frame in the current frame so that it will accumulate previous frames such that it appears the arrow is "growing" instead of just moving? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\begin{document}
\foreach \posy in {-0.45,-0.35,...,2.45}
{
   
\begin{tikzpicture}

\centering
\resizebox{0.75\linewidth}{!}{% 
    
    % grid
     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,2}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,2}
            \node[box,label={[label distance=-5mm]90:}] at (\x,\y){};
    
    % draw
    \draw [->, blue, ultra thin] (0,\posy) -- (0,\posy + 0.1){};
    
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If you want your arrow to "grow", why are you changing its starting point with `\draw [->, blue, ultra thin] (0,\posy)`? You could just make your arrow start from the same point on each frame, for example with `\draw [->, blue, ultra thin] (0,-0.45) -- (0,\posy + 0.1){};`.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain clearly. I want to retain all the arrowheads. If I do as you say, there will be one long line with a single arrow head